# Add help button to angular-formly fields

Tags: angular-formly

I'm looking to add a 'help' button to each field of my formly-form. When clicking on the button, the help text for that field is displayed in a separate bootstrap column next to the form.

I'm able to add a button to each field using a templateManipulator and insert the field's ID into the options.data object.

```
fConfig.templateManipulators.preWrapper.push(function(template, options, scope) {
    if (options.data.showHelpForField === undefined) { return template; }
        return "<div><button ng-click='vm.helpText" + vm.helpTextLookup[options.data.showHelpForField] +"'>?</button>" + template + "</div>";
    });
}
```

I have all the help texts, stored in an object with the field IDs as keys. I intend to display up the appropriate help text when each button is clicked, however as you can see `vm.helpTextLookup` and `vm.helpText` live outside the scope of the field.

The HTML to render to form looks like this

```
<form name="inputForm" ng-submit="vm.onSubmit()">
    <formly-form fields="vm.fields">
        <button type="submit">Save</button>
    </formly-form>
</form>
<div>{{ vm.helpText }}</div>
```

What would be the best way to accomplish this? I'm I going down the right path, or did I miss something in the formly docs? I put together a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/exj22x7m/14/) with the basics mocked up.